# vb.net, Xtrareport :How to show the header of an Xrtable on each page the Xrtable expands to?

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I use DevExpress Xtrareports. I have an Xrtable control inside the report. When I print the report, the Xrtable header appears only on the first page. I want the header to appear on each page the Xrtable expands to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new detail band, in the detail band add a Group Header Band, in this band add a table with header, in its properties set RepeatEveryPage to true.
In the Detail Band just add the table with the data in datasource.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do that is to use the PageHeaderBand that's designed specifically for this purpose: [PageHeaderBand](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.PageHeaderBand.class)